# Open SWTBot test Recorder with Eclipse RCP application

Tags: eclipse, user-interface, testing, eclipse-rcp, swtbot

I want to use SWTBot Test Recorder with my Eclipse RCP Application but the SWTBot recorder doesn't start with my application, when I try to run it.

What I've done with Eclipse:

> File > New > Other > Run Test Recorder > Record Test Senario on another RCP Application

Configuration:

- VM: `-Dorg.eclipse.swtbot.generator.enable=true`
- Run a Product: My Application
- I have the plugins for SWTBot

Run >>> My application start without SWTBot Test Recorder

---

I have already seen this post https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=1078197&goto=1734430&#msg_1734430 and it doesn't work for me.
SWTBot Test Recorder can start with Eclipse IDE.

Thank you,

Antoine

Answer (score 0):

This post should help:

https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=1078197&goto=1734430&#msg_1734430

It worked for me.
You need to make sure you add the plugins to the target platform (Window->Preference->Plugin Development->Target Platform)

Comment: Thank you for your response but I have already seen that post (cf my question). With the same configuration without Target Platforme (but swtbot is already on my eclipse installation) it doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here. All releated plug-ins for SWTBot selected in `Run Configuration` and I have VM arguments: `-Dorg.eclipse.swtbot.generator.enable=true` but SWTBot Recorder Dialog will not open with RCP app launching.

**Workaround** that worked for me: 
**Start the SWTBot Recorder Dialog programmatically** from one of your plug-ins: see
https://wiki.eclipse.org/SWTBot/Generator#Programatically.2C_from_a_plugin

1. add all SWTBot plug-ins to your Plugin from which you want to start the SWTBot Recorder programmatically
2. add following Import to your class from which to start the Dialog: `import org.eclipse.swtbot.generator.ui.StartupRecorder;`
3. the following Code opens the Recorder window: `StartupRecorder.openRecorder(null);`